# How does aircrack-ng suite view Clients on networks we are not connected to?

Tags: wifi, tcpdump, wireshark

I noticed with the tool **airodump-ng** which is apart of the **aircrack-ng** suite we can view all networks around us along with Client MAC address's which are connected to these networks.

How can I acheive similar without this tool, I assume some common packages could be used such as **tcpdump**, **nmap**, **wireshark,** etc...

Comment: aircrack is free and open source you can download the source and copy the parts you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID
```

the grep will filter out the rubbish and simply display the networks around you.